# Strange timeout like error on production server (Network Error(tcp_error))

Tags: php, server

I have an application running for my company that uses very slow scripts. One of the pages used for this is running a SQL query for about 5 minutes then run PHP in about 20 minutes.

After this delay the server sends me an error that says :

Network Error (tcp_error) 
- 503 error - A communication error occurred: ""

I have already tried to solve the problem by increasing the PHP max execution time without success.

If you want access to the code, I can give it but the code isn't really easy to understand.

Do you know how could I fix this error?

Comment: You mean you try to control a server side script that executes for half an hour using a browser?

Comment: Yes @arkascha . This is how my company is doing thing

Comment: That is a strategy that does not offer any robustness. You should try to compute such stuff in background, headless, and only use a monitoring solution to track progress and success.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the problem is a computation-heavy or the script processes lots of database data so try some of these approaches:

1. Try to paginate the data fetching, try to fetch the data into smaller chunks.
2. Of not possible try to hide and move the computation somewhere else:

   - Load the html first and then load the data via ajax
   - Try to process the data in a database procedure (quessing mysql, look on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)
   - Make a service with asynchronous communication for example a script the communicates with rabbit mq. Process the data on the service and send it back to the main application. In case of php you may need another application that supports websockets and node.js for this part.
3. Try to cache data that is not computed so often. Eg. when fetching some data after processing it cache the result in a mongodb so if not affected fetch it first from mongo and do not recompute them.
4. Consider precomputing as much data and store them either in a relational database (mysql postgresql) of a non relational one (mongodb, couchbase).
5. Also ins some application parts try to use other technologies beyond relational databases in order to make them efficient (eg. elastic search for searching or neo4j for mapping relations).
6. Try to split the computation in smaller chunks and either via db triggers during write and update execute them. An alternate approach is when writing either via using services or on the write logic itself to do the computation ins smaller parts.

Also **BEFORE** doing anything above try to analyze where the code slows down how much does it take to process the data and how much data are being fetched.

Furthermore in case of a background process execution you need some extra data and a way to keep track of the process. Also you can run the following as well:

```
<?php

  system("php someheavyprocessingscript.php &");
  //Load Html do some stuff here
?>
```

Via system and the ending `&` on the executing command you run the process to the background. Usually I would prefer more like a service approach and via some websockets to fetch the result to the frontend via a RabbitMq communication.

Also consider googling/duckduckgoing the following keywords: `xdebug-profiler`, `service-oriented architecture` it will give you some points on how to solve it + some extra knowledge.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will look into these options. Basically code is about sum and average of huge dataset and a lot of parameters. With this information, do you see what would be theorically the best thing to do from option 1 to 5 ?

Comment: There's not such a thing as the best option is about looking what suits you best according to knowledge and resources. Usually what you need to do is: - split the computation on smaller chunks - executing elsewhere - to execute it as less often as possible or all/some of the above.

Comment: Ps plz click on the up arrow in my answer :p